# Difference between traversing of linked list in the print and append methods

Tags: python, data-structures

```
def viewList(self):
        if self.start == None:
            print("List is empty!")
        else:
            temp = self.start
            while (temp):
                print(temp.data, end="-->")
                temp = temp.next
```

```
def insertLast(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if self.start == None:
            self.start = newNode
        else:
            temp = self.start
            while (temp.next):
                temp = temp.next
            temp.next = newNode
```

In the two above methods, we need to traverse until the last node so that we can append or print the required linked list but, why is it so that while traversing in the `viewList` method we use `while(temp):` but in the `insertLast` method we use `while(temp.next):`. What's the difference between the two, please explain it to me.

Comment: The loop in `InsertLast` needs to *stop* at the last node, i.e., the one with next == None.  The loop in `viewList` iterates *past* the last node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, it is just way of writing code:

viewList() can be re-written to use `while (temp.next)`:

```
def viewList(self):
        if self.start == None:
            print("List is empty!")
        else:
            temp = self.start
            while (temp.next):
                print(temp.data, end="-->")
                temp = temp.next
            print(temp.data, end="-->")
```

insertLast() can be re-written to use `while (temp)`:

```
def insertLast(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        if self.start == None:
            self.start = newNode
        else:
            prev = NULL
            temp = self.start
            while (temp):
                prev = temp
                temp = temp.next
            prev.next = newNode
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the structure of a linked list:

```
Element1 --> Element2 --> ... --> ElementN --> null
```

When printing a list, we want to make sure that the *current* element is not `null`.

When inserting a value at the end of the list, we are checking whether the *next* element  is `null`.